# Why can't I see the same page that I requested?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-3.6, google-image-search

I've been learning Python and tried Web Scraping.
I could manage to scrape Google Result Page for a normal Google Search, though the page was depreciated idk why.
Tried the same for Google Images, and it is depreciated as well. It doesn't appear the same as it was appearing in the browser.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/AqqFgZsb)'s my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

search = input("Search for : ")
params = {"tbm": "isch", "source": "hp", "q": search}
r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params)
print("URL :", r.url)
print("Status : ", r.status_code, "\n\n")

f = open("ImageResult.html", "w+")
f.write(r.text)
```

For example, I search for "Goku".
The Google Image returns [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&q=Goku) page.

When I click on the first image, a popup opens. Or say I press ctrl+click. I reach [this](https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fvignette.wikia.nocookie.net%2Fdragonball%2Fimages%2F5%2F5b%2FGokusteppingoutofaspaceship.jpg%2Frevision%2Flatest%2Fscale-to-width-down%2F224%3Fcb%3D20150325220848&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fdragonball.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FGoku&docid=Go0nffXKghxLJM&tbnid=s3oJndZhgIPtBM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwi4sobC6qLYAhVKvo8KHXPaAl4QMwjTASgAMAA..i&w=224&h=498&bih=700&biw=1366&q=Goku&ved=0ahUKEwi4sobC6qLYAhVKvo8KHXPaAl4QMwjTASgAMAA&iact=mrc&uact=8) page.

On this page I can see that the actual image's URL can be accessed through maybe the current url or the link at the "View Image" button. But the issue is, I can't reach this page/popup in the version of the page that I am able to get when I request this page.

**UPDATE** : I'm sharing the [page](https://codepen.io/choubeyaakash77/pen/MrbOLx) I am getting.

Comment: first: Google normally sends page which uses JavaScript to put elements. If browser doesn't use javaScript then it sends page with different tags. `requests` can't run JavaScript so it gets different tags than you get in browser and you see in DevTool in Chrome/Firefox. So turn off JavaScript in browser and load Google to see what `requests` can get.

Comment: Thanks a lot `@furas`, that was the exact answer I was looking for!!
So is there an alternative to `requests` that can run JavaScript? I think according to my need, I need the JavaScript enabled output.

Comment: You can use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  It to control browser which will load page and run JavaScript.can also use "headless" browsers (which don't dislay browser window) like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [PhantomPy](https://phantompy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). See also [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). But I would try to work with Google page which doesn't use JavaScript - mostly there are the same data but in different HTML's tags. `Selenium` have to use browser so it works slower.

Comment: see also [list of headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers)

Comment: BTW after you write `r.text` to file you can use `import webbrowser ;  webbrowser.open("ImageResult.html")` to see downloaded page in browser. It should open your default web browser to display this file.

Comment: Thanks a lot `@furas`. I've been reading about all those stuff yesterday, ended up using Selenium and yeah, it is slow. I'll check out PhantomPY, PhantomJS and Splash. The thing is, I can't find that same content without JS. I guess even Google is using some webscraper to get the individual images from the websites..and then showing it up through JS. Maybe I'll switch to multiple Image Search Engines instead.
Thanks a lot still. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a lot of factors like user agent string , cookies and also google experiments . Google is known for serving different ways of same content for many users.On search ,Google loads different pages based on site speed and user agent.Google also randomly runs experiments on searchpage design,etc before rollng in public to implement A/B testing dynamically.

Comment: Whoa! Any alternative to what I am trying to do?

Comment: Yes you can design your web parser or scraper based on your python output and also try to find better classes and generalisation of data . You can also try to reload the script to avoid any experiment please upvote if the answer was correct

Answer (score 0):

Google Organic results have very little JavaScript and you still can parse data from the `<script>` tags.

Besides that, the most often problem why you don't see the same results as in your browser is because there's no `user-agent` being passed into request `headers` thus when no `user-agent` is specified while using `requests` library, it defaults to [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and Google understands that it's a bot/script, then it blocks a request (*or whatever it does*) and you receive a different HTML with different CSS selectors. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

requests.get('URL', headers=headers)
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to spend time trying to bypass blocks from Google and figuring out why certain things don't work as they should, and you don't have to maintain the parser over time.

Very simple example code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "how to create minecraft server",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result["link"], sep="\n")

----------
'''
https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360058525452-How-to-Setup-a-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Server
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server
https://www.idtech.com/blog/creating-minecraft-server
# other results
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.